# OnClickListener inside a loop throwing IndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: android, for-loop, onclick, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to create what's basically a list of cards repeating one after another, based from an array I have via a loop.

For some reason though, setting my OnClickListener inside the loop is causing an OOB exception but from what I see it shouldn't be so I appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

My loop:

```
for(FAQNumber = 0; FAQNumber < questions.length; FAQNumber++){
    stack.add(new FAQCard(questions[FAQNumber], answers[FAQNumber]));
    (stack.get(FAQNumber)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("title", questions[FAQNumber]);
            bundle.putSerializable("position", FAQNumber);
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), QuestionAnswer.class).putExtras(bundle));
        }
    });
}
```

`questions` is an Array declared earlier in the method, containing just a few strings. And `stack` behaves as a List.

I'm getting the OOB error on `bundle.putSerializable("title", questions[FAQNumber]);` when it's trying to add the `questions[5]` (if my `questions[]` contained 5 values). But I don't understand how that happens because the loop should stop before `FAQNumber` is equal to 5?

All I'm trying to do with the above loop is pass the right question to the bundle so that when a card is pressed, the questions match up.

Anyway, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FAQNumber seems to be defined outside of the for-loop rather than inside.  This means it continues to exist after the loop is done ... is this intentional?  If there are 5 items in `questions` then after the loop terminates FAQNumber will be equal to 5 (due to the last `FAQNumber++`).

The `OnClickListener`'s `onClick(View v)` method is not called until the button is actually clicked.  At this time, it's looking for FAQNumber **which is now equal to 5**.  The key thing to understand here is that when you put `FAQNumber` into the onClick method, it's going to actually go and look for the current value of `FAQNumber` at the time of the click, not at the time that you defined the method.  The reason you're getting the `OutOfBoundsException` at this line is not because the error is happening while you're looping but because the button's click behavior is located here so this is where the error is thrown.  Your loop is actually executing just fine.

Instead, you're going to want to store FAQNumber as an instance variable on the view you're clicking like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  stack.add(new FAQCard(questions[i], answers[i]));
  // Replace YourViewClass with whatever you're getting off the stack
  YourViewClass obj = (stack.get(FAQNumber));
  obj.setFaqNumber(i); // You'll need to add this method
  obj.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        // You'll need to add the getFaqNumber() getter as well
        bundle.putSerializable("title", questions[getFaqNumber()]);
        bundle.putSerializable("position", getFaqNumber());
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), QuestionAnswer.class).putExtras(bundle));
    }
});
```

Comment: Got it working, thanks! Never knew that OnClicks were set like that, I figured they were set to the view to be triggered later

Comment: They are set to be triggered later but, the code in the event handler is executed at click time.

Comment: @hatboysam Also, the reason it was defined outside is because Eclipse was complaining it needed to be `final` and of course it couldn't then be iterated by the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @hatboysam's answer I also got it working by changing to a while:

```
while(FAQNumber < questions.length){
    final int i = FAQNumber;
    final FAQCard FAQ = new FAQCard(questions[FAQNumber], answers[FAQNumber]);
    FAQ.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Create a new bundle to pass to the browser
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            // Inform which feed item was selected
            bundle.putSerializable("title", questions[i]);
            bundle.putSerializable("position", i);
            // Start the new activity and pass on the bundle
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), QuestionAnswer.class).putExtras(bundle));
        }
    });
    stack.add(FAQ);
    FAQNumber++;
};
```

Comment: The important thing here is not the `while` but that the `int i` is local to the loop and final and therefore is considered a constant in the `OnClickListener`.